# Why when I zoom in or zoom out my elements size changes despite using rem?

Tags: html, css

I'm implementing a project and I have used CSS `position` attribute to place a button inside an input, everything is ok and even I have no problem in responsive mode, coincidentally I wanted to zoom-in to check something and I realized when I zoom-in or zoom-out a gap between the top or bottom of the input gets made and in some sizes there is no gap and everything is fine again, I use `rem` for all of my CSS attributes because as far as I know `rem` is scalable with `viewport` and this zoom-in or zoom-out is something related to `viewport` size, so logically if I use `rem` there shouldn't be any gap when I zoom out or zoom in but there is!

I even changed my unites from `rem` to `PX`(it was recommended in another question similar to my question), still the same problem and I checked it on different browsers, each browser had this problem but their behavior and the gap they make is different in different zoom sizes. furthermore I have no issue in responsive breakpoints or sizes and everything just work fine.

relation between `viewport` and zooming-in or zooming-out based on the **MDN**:

Your viewport is everything that is currently visible, notably, the "what is a viewport" section, and perhaps some of the navigation menu. The size of the viewport depends on the size of the screen, whether the browser is in fullscreen mode or not, and whether or not the user **zoomed-in**.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Viewport_concepts

relation between `viewport` and `rem`:

For responsive web pages, the size of web elements changes with the size of the viewport. CSS enables you to declare font size using absolute units like pixels (px) or relative units like percentages, em, or rem units.

https://blog.hubspot.com/website/css-rem#:~:text=Rem%20(short%20for%20%E2%80%9Croot%2D,1rem%20will%20also%20equal%2016px.

so the question is: because the behavior is different across multiple browser, is this button repositioning due to zooming in or out, related to browser structure or programming or is it just something else and what is logic behind of that?

```css
/*Default Adjustments*/

:root {
  --color-secondary: #00acc1;
  --color-accent: #F86F03;
  --color-body: #212121;
  --color-text: #FBFFDC;
  --colorButton: #847f7d;
  --colorBorder: #A8A196;
}

*,
*::before,
*::after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

*,
 ::placeholder {
  color: var(--color-text);
}

html {
  font-size: 10px;
}

body {
  font-family: "Inter", arial, helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  line-height: 1.5;
  background: var(--color-body);
}

.btn {
  background: var(--colorButton);
  border: .1rem solid var(--colorBorder);
  border-radius: .3rem;
}


/*Basic divs*/

.adjust {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.whole {
  background: var(--color-secondary);
  padding: 1.5rem;
  border-radius: 0.6rem;
  margin-top: 2rem;
}

.add {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  margin-bottom: 1.3rem;
}

.addButton {
  position: absolute;
  cursor: pointer;
  top: 0.27rem;
  right: 8rem;
  font-size: 1.3rem;
  border: 0;
  border-radius: 0 .3rem .3rem 0;
  background: var(--colorButton);
}

.add input {
  outline: none;
  text-indent: 0.5rem;
  font-size: 1.3rem;
  background: var(--colorBorder);
  border: .3rem solid var(--colorButton);
  border-radius: .5rem;
}

.add input::placeholder {
  font-size: 1.25rem;
}
```

```html
<div class="adjust">
  <div class="whole">
    <form class="add">
      <input class="addBook" type="text" required maxlength="50" pattern="\S(.*\S)?" title="Your book name can't start or end with white space and should include at least 
            1 non-white space character" placeholder="e.g Harry Potter" name="" id="" />
      <button class=" btn addButton">Add</button>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

**images**:

[image]

that's 100% zooming size and everything is ok

[image]

that's 90% of zooming size and there is a gap in the top

[image]

that's 80% of zooming size and everything is ok again!

the same results occur in zooming-in , so if this problem is related to my code, why then it isn't constant in every zooming sizes and if it's not related to my code, so  what's happening under the hood?

Comment: It's likely just how the browser renders your components as it has to translate rem to actual (not CSS) pixel sizes. The only way to ensure your gaps don't appear is, for example, to set your `top` to 0 and `bottom` to 0 too. Sometimes a gap appears on the top. Sometimes it appears at the bottom with your code on various browsers, dependent on the zoom level.

Comment: as far as I understand this situation is like "it is what it is" and I cant help to fix it(setting top and bottom=0 fixed this problem, I  mean for other situation and examples involved with zoom)@Adam

Comment: and do you think I should just ignore this zooming issue and just stick to responsive or it just important?@Adam

Answer (score 0):

I think this is related to absolute position , I've experienced that before .
However to solve that you can add a wrapper around your button , this wrapper is a flexbox .

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <button class="btn addButton">Add</button>
</div>
```

```
.wrapper {
    height: 100%;
    width: fit-content;
    padding: .3rem 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    float: left;
    border-radius: 0 .3rem .3rem 0;
    display: flex;
    /*To keep item centered so gap will not appear*/
    align-items: center;
}
.addButton {
    font-size: 1.3rem;
    border: 0;
    background: var(--colorButton);
    border-radius: 0;
    -webkit-border-radius: 0;
    -moz-border-radius: 0;
    -ms-border-radius: 0;
    -o-border-radius: 0;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```